# How to arrange a text that is a combination of English and Persian words from right to left in HTML title tag

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I am doing an ASP.NET Framework MVC project and I have a title tag in my "layout.cshtml" like below :

```
<title>ViewBag.Title</title>
```

this "layout.cshtml" is the layout page of my "index.cshtml" and this "ViewBag" gets data from the "index.cshtml" like below :

```
ViewBag.Title = "Transaction های" + " روزانه";
```

My problem is that it will be shown like below text in tab of the browser :

> Transaction های روزانه

But I need it to be shown like below text in browser tab :

> های روزانه Transaction

How can I do this?
Any help will be appriciated!

Comment: `float: right` may be.. ?? ‍♀️

Comment: Sorry friend. It did not worked

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED:** I found a way, just forget about `ViewBag.Title` and put the text in , like this:

`<title> های روزانه Transaction</title>`

It does not work indirectly, but only if you put the text directly into the `<title>`

[image: Picture of link working]

I hope that helps, not sure if it will work for you though ;)

Comment: No, it did not work again. I think the Microsoft must think about that!

Comment: I found a way, just forget about ViewBag.Title and put the text in <title>, like this:

```<title> های روزانه Transaction</title>```